# ajax, jquery ,respose error (500 internal server error) & xml parsing error

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, web-services, asmx

i am unable to get the response from ajax please guide me how to resolve this error i am getting successful data from the server i have checked it in fiddle web debugger and still ajax is showing error ... XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{6b0a1ac2-50ab-4053-9f71-8ae49202288d} Line Number 1, Column 1:

```
 $j.ajax({

            type:"POST",
            url:'http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit',
            data: 'Celsius=12',
            crossDomain:true,
            async: false,
            success:function(response)
            {
                alert("Success Full Done"+response.string);
            } });
```

Answer (score -1):

Cross domain posts do not allow for XML I believe. You can try using jsonp though.

To do that add

```
datatype:'jsonp'
```

Also when you use JSONP it is not possible to do a post. Only GET is possible with JSONP.

Comment: hey  hi @hunda I have used jsonp but still getting 500 server error